# Combining multiple sub-documents into a new doc in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to query multiple sub-documents in MongoDB and return as a single doc.
I think the aggregation framework is the way to go, but, can't see to get it exactly right.

Take the following docs:

```
{
    "board_id": "1",
    "hosts": 
     [{
        "name": "bob",
        "ip": "10.1.2.3"
     },
    {
         "name": "tom",
         "ip": "10.1.2.4"
    }]
 }

{
    "board_id": "2",
    "hosts": 
    [{
        "name": "mickey",
        "ip": "10.2.2.3"
    },
    {
        "name": "mouse",
        "ip": "10.2.2.4"
    }]
}

{
     "board_id": "3",
     "hosts": 
    [{
        "name": "pavel",
        "ip": "10.3.2.3"
    },
    {
        "name": "kenrick",
        "ip": "10.3.2.4"
     }]
}
```

Trying to get a query result like this:

```
{
    "hosts": 
    [{
        "name": "bob",
        "ip": "10.1.2.3"
    },
    {
         "name": "tom",
         "ip": "10.1.2.4"
    },
    {
         "name": "mickey",
         "ip": "10.2.2.3"
    },
    {
        "name": "mouse",
        "ip": "10.2.2.4"
    }, 
    {
         "name": "pavel",
         "ip": "10.3.2.3"
     },
     {
        "name": "kenrick",
        "ip": "10.3.2.4"
     }]
}
```

I've tried this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([ { $unwind: '$hosts' }, { $project : { name: 1, hosts: 1, _id: 0 }} ])
```

But it's not quite what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely do this with aggregate. Let's assume your data is in collection named board, so please replace it with whatever your collection name is.

```
db.board.aggregate([
{$unwind:"$hosts"},
{$group:{_id:null, hosts:{$addToSet:"$hosts"}}},
{$project:{_id:0, hosts:1}}
]).pretty()
```

it will return

```
    {
        "hosts" : [
            {
                "name" : "kenrick",
                "ip" : "10.3.2.4"
            },
            {
                "name" : "pavel",
                "ip" : "10.3.2.3"
            },
            {
                "name" : "mouse",
                "ip" : "10.2.2.4"
            },
            {
                "name" : "mickey",
                "ip" : "10.2.2.3"
            },
            {
                "name" : "tom",
                "ip" : "10.1.2.4"
            },
            {
                "name" : "bob",
                "ip" : "10.1.2.3"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: The answer is correct, but caution must be advised when using `$addToSet` with ordered data - in that case, `$push` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

So your basic problem here is that the arrays are contained in separate documents. So while you are correct to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array for processing, in order to bring the content into a single array you would need to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) the result across documents, and [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) the content to the result array:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$hosts" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "hosts": { "$push": "$hosts" }
    }}
])
```

So just as `$unwind` will "deconstruct" the array elements, the `$push` accumulator in `$group` brings "reconstructs" the array. And since there is no other key to "group" on, this brings all the elements into a single array.

Note that a `null` grouping key is only really practical when the resulting document would not exceed the BSON limit. Otherwise you are better off leaving the individual elements as documents in themselves.

Optionally remove the `_id` with an additional `$project` if required.